# How to defer loading css when using import

Tags: javascript, css

```
import 'react-dates/lib/css/_datepicker.css'
```

The css above is not critical, so I can defer loading it.

How to defer loading css when using `import`?

google gives me how to do it using `<link>`

Comment: i am not sure but let see if this is helpful. https://medium.com/webpack/link-rel-prefetch-preload-in-webpack-51a52358f84c

Comment: Its important to know where is this import, if its on root components, or on some component that can be `import`ed dynamically itself

Comment: is there others CSS you import along side this CSS, or it the only CSS in this component

Comment: This is in some component which is not always rendered (I guess that satisfied can be `dynamically imported`) @CaptainMhmdrz_A , there are other '*.js' files I import

Answer (score 1):

If you are using webpack, you can use its `dynamic import` feature:

```js
const delay = () => import(`react-dates/lib/css/_datepicker.css`)
setTimeout(() => delay(), 0)
```

Comment: I just don't understand why Webpack loaders can't detect dynamic imports and automatically add a style tag with the defer attribute, but that setTimeout hack does it! Thanks